# What is the general approach to having three hands on a clock all rotate on the same axis but at different speeds?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, gears, mechanisms

I want to build an art piece which would have three disks rotating all about the same axis at different speeds. Mechanically this would function just like a clock with hour, minute and second hands (except a larger shape instead of a single rod as a hand, and not the same speeds as in a clock).

However, I've not been able to find a diagram of how the gearing works for having three things all on the same axis at different speeds.

Can anyone point me to a diagram of how this is handled in standard three-hand clocks, so that I could adapt the design to my desired shapes and speeds?

Comment: This is very similar to https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/57159/connect-two-motors-to-different-planes-and-rotate-them-on-the-same-center-point.

Comment: Buy a cheap electric clock and take the gearbox apart to see how it works. Did you search YouTube?

Comment: Gears. It doesn't take much to transfer torque to an off axis gear, and bring it back at another axial point.  One reason to stop at 3 hands rather than aim for 5 is that it is simple to support an off axis shaft against each side of the case (front and back) of such a gear box

Comment: It's pretty easy actually. Use concentric shafts with bearings between them. Put a gear on each shaft, then mesh that gear with additional gears off axis to create your gear ratios. Or even just use 3 different motors if you don't care about synchronicity.